# ES6 Promises do not exist in controllers, helpers under Lightning Locker

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

Very simple example: Create a Lightning component with Lightning Locker enabled, and add to its init method:

```
console.log(Promise);
```

The logged result will be `undefined`. It would appear that Lightning Locker hides this native ES6 feature from browsers. In theory I could add a polyfill but that would seem to be needlessly convoluted just to get a native feature working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct - Promise has not been security reviewed yet - please open a case to track this and let the support tech know that I have already opened bug W-3193387 to track the work. This is targeted for the next patch that deploys a week from today.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I don't personally have case-opening authority at my company but I will forward this to my colleague who does.

Comment: Hi Doug, I can now see ES6 promises inside my sandbox as of today. Thank you.